# ProcessingJS: Draw doesn't appear to be looping?

Tags: javascript, processing

ProcessingJS: My draw doesn't appear to be looping. I'm trying to make a simple game where I have a box at the bottom, and the blocks fall from the top and you need to catch them. But draw doesn't seem to be looping like it should so as a temporary solution I'm using redraw upon key pressed.
I've tested other programs written by others on my web server and they work.
Is there a problem in my code?

EDIT: changed code to conform with suggestions - still not working
example at: http://jordantheriault.com/processing/test.html

EDIT2: I've narrowed it down to the nested for loops in draw.

```
//Size of each cell box
int cellWidth = 25;

//Width and height of playable space in cells
int w = 8, h = 15;

//Player position
int playerX = 0, playerY = h-1;

//Score
int score = 0;
int lives = 10;

int[][] map = new int[w][h];
// 1 = player
// 2 = object to catch

void setup()
{
  size(cellWidth*w+1, cellWidth*h+1);
  background(51);
  fill(255);

  frameRate(30);

  //starting position for player
  map[playerX][playerY] = 1;

}

void draw(){  
    if(lives > 0)
    {
        background(51);

        //Draw objects onto map
        for(int i = 0; i < width-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < height-1; j++)
            {
                if(map[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    fill(255);
                    rect(i * cellWidth, j * cellWidth, cellWidth, cellWidth);
                }
                if(map[i][j] == 2)
                {
                    fill(200);
                    rect(i * cellWidth, j * cellWidth, cellWidth, cellWidth);
                }

            }
        }

        //Generate new object to catch
        if (frameCount%5==0) {
            //Move squares
            //TODO

            //Generate new
            newSquare = random(0,w-1);
            println(newSquare);
            map[newSquare][0] = 2;
        }
        text("Score: " + score, 5, 15); 
    }
    else
    {
        text("Game over! Press x to start again.", 10, (h*cellWidth)/2); 
        noLoop();
    }
}

void keyPressed() 

{
    //Todo: check for collisions

    if (key == 'a') {
            if(playerX != 0)
            {
                if(map[playerX-1][playerY] == 2 || map[playerX][playerY-1] == 2)
                    score++;
                map[playerX][playerY] = 0;
                playerX -= 1;
                map[playerX][playerY] = 1;
                println("Left Pressed");
                redraw();
             }
        }
     if (key == 'd') {
        if(playerX != w-1)
            {
                if(map[playerX+1][playerY] == 2 || map[playerX][playerY-1] == 2)
                    score++;
                map[playerX][playerY] = 0;
                playerX += 1;
                map[playerX][playerY] = 1;
                println("Right pressed");
                redraw();
             }
        }
        if(key == 'x' && lives < 1)
        {
            score = 0;
            lives = 10;
            //reset game
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want event based updating, you'll need to call `redraw()` at the end of your event handlers (before they would return, not literally only at the end of the function definition) so that the `draw` function gets called. Don't use `loop()`, as that simply turns the automatic next-frame-scheduling code back on (the `loop`/`noLoop` functions only control whether the sketch should be automatically scheduling frames).

Also, note that using `noLoop` with a `frameRate` won't do anything. The first voids the second.

Finally, note that `frameRate(300)` is insane ;) You're asking Processing to run all your draw code in a fraction over 3 milliseconds. That's not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mike! I'm actually not looking to do event-based, I've just used it because without the redraw, it doesn't loop! Any suggestion for how I can get it to actually loop? As-is, it doesn't loop at all!

Comment: well yeah, obviously if you call noLoop, your sketch isn't going to be looping. Set frameRate to something sensible, like 30, and remove the noLoop. Done, your sketch will constantly redraw. However, note that in your question you explicitly state "I need to redraw upon mouseclick", so if you've changed your mind about that, you should also update your post.

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the answers. It's however still not looping. (should be seeing random light gray boxes appear at the top. The 'a' and 'd' key should also move the white box at the bottom) [example](http://jordantheriault.com/processing/test.html)

Comment: it's either noLoop + redraw, or looping without redraw calls. Also, when I paste your update code into Processing, it doesn't compile, so you need to fix at least one thing (but in reality quite a few things) before this can be tested by others again.

Comment: I've fixed it, it was many small mistakes with the additions of your suggestions. Thanks for your time!